# Is it possible to watch the tcp connection packets on a connect call from the command line in linux?

Tags: tcp, connection, diagnostic

Basically I want to do something like strace ssh user@host and instead of seeing the system calls, I want to watch the tcp connection packets as the connection is established.

I'm having this weird problem between two specific machines, where b can connect to a but a can't connect to b most of the time, and when it is able to connect the connection is very slow and it takes a  minute just to get the ssh greeting.

Sounds like packets being dropped, so I'm looking for a way to diagnose.
I know I can fire up wireshark or something (suggestions welcome) but I figured if there was something simple and specific to a process that would be handy.

Comment: so I just found tcptrack which is showing me that a SYN packet is sent to start the connection, and no SYN-ACK (or anything else) ever comes back. Now what do I do?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall allowing incoming but not outgoing, or vice versa. You can use tcpdump to dig further: https://serverfault.com/questions/217605/how-to-capture-ack-or-syn-packets-by-tcpdump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the sniff with tcpdump perfectly

**install tcpdump**

on debian,ubuntu

```
apt install tcpdump
```

on centOS

```
yum install tcpdump
```

**listen on tcp packets**

at first list your  interfaces

```
tcpdump -D
```

list/capture  packets on interface eth0

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0
```

list/capture ONLY TCP packets on interface eth0

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 tcp
```

**screenshots**

[tcpdump Display Available Interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGyHq.png)

[tcpdump Capture show Packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGPR9.png)

Answer (score -1):

So I found my problem, it turned out to be a script generating lots of iptables drop rules. I'm guessing one of the ips it was blocking was on one of the routes between the two machines, so it was intermittent.
Removing the iptables rules made the problem go away.